# Is there a way to discard a number stored using malloc/realloc when printing the result?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

**What the code does:**

1. Asks the person to enter x amount of numbers and finishes by entering a " 0 " (zero).
2. The numbers are then saved and stored using malloc/realloc.
3. With the help of a bubble sort, numbers entered will be sorted and printed out in an ascending order.

> 

**My problem:** when the sorted numbers are printed out, it also adds the 0 (zero), which only purpose is to finish the task and not be added to the list of numbers entered by the person. For example if I add: 4,5,8,1,3,1,10 ("0" to finish). The printing result will be: 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10.

I'm new to C (worked with it for only about 2 weeks). So far I've tried changing " i " to 1 in this for-loop. However, all it does is to basically shift everything one step (?). Causing the 0 only to go from being first to last: 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 0.

```
> //Bubble sort:
>         for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++)
```

I assume using free() will only work when you're looking to free all the memory stored and not one particular number? Any help is appreciated. Further, yes this is a work assignment :).

> 

**Here's the code:**

```
int main()
{
    int nr = 1;
    int temp;
    int *numberStore = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int inputNumber = 0;

    while (nr != 0)
    {
        printf("Add numbers to be stored (finish by entering 0): ");
        scanf("%d", &nr);
        printf("\n");
        numberStore[inputNumber] = nr;
        inputNumber++;
        numberStore = realloc(numberStore, (inputNumber + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }

    //Bubble sort:
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (inputNumber - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (numberStore[j] > numberStore[j + 1])
            {
                temp = numberStore[j];
                numberStore[j] = numberStore[j + 1];
                numberStore[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //Prints the stored numbers in ascending order:
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", numberStore[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So just `inputNumber -= 1;` before sorting, no?

Comment: @KamilCuk - Didn't work, thanks anyway.

Comment: As @KamilCuk says: "Remember to handle errors - `realloc` and `scanf` may fail"

Comment: OT: regarding: `numberStore = realloc(numberStore, (inputNumber + 1) * sizeof(int));`  1) the function: `realloc()` is expecting the 'size' parameter to be of type `size_t`, not `int`.  The result is the compiler outputs a warning message.  2)  the function can fail.  When it fails an unrecoverable memory leak occurs.  Suggest:    int *temp =  realloc( numberStore, (inputNumber + 1) * sizeof(int) );  if( ! temp ) { // handle error, cleanup, and exit }  numberStore = temp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply don't add `0` to your data

```
while (nr != 0)
{
    printf("Add numbers to be stored (finish by entering 0): ");
    scanf("%d", &nr);
    printf("\n");
    if (nr != 0)                // only add if not 0
    {
        numberStore[inputNumber] = nr;
        inputNumber++;
        numberStore = realloc(numberStore, (inputNumber + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Or, same idea, slightly more compact: `if (nr == 0) break;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first part solved my problem, by adding the " if (nr != 0) ". Will try the other ones as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just decrement the count of numbers before sorting:

```
    numberStore = realloc(numberStore, (inputNumber + 1) * sizeof(int));
}

// yay - the algorithm thinks there are less numbers in the array
// the last element is just zero - don't care
inputNumber -= 1;

//Bubble sort:
for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++)
```

This would just overallocate the array for one element. A better alternative would be to make decision to add element to the array depending on the value - don't add array element if read value is 0. Remember to handle errors - `realloc` and `scanf` may fail.

Comment: The reason for using " 0 " is because we were forced to in this work assignment. Besides this, there were other criterias as well that needed to be included. Thus why the code. I also missunderstood you the first time where to add the < inputNumber -= 1; >. But I tried it again. However, it failed to print at all. It just finished the coding and did nothing :). Appreciate the help.